# How to do a distribution in a racket list

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I have a list of 6 digits' (1 2 3 4 5 6) for example. When choosing a digit, it distributes its value (in +1) to the numbers after it:

'(1 2 3 4 5 6)
I choose the 4th digit, it is 4.

The program then:

```
4-1 & 5+1
3-1 & 6+1
2-1 & 1+1
1-1 & 2+1
```

Because once he did it at 6, go back to the beginning of the list to continue distributing himself.
It stops when the starting value reaches 0

I already have the function to choose the number, but I have no idea for the distribution like that.

Hoping to have been pretty clear,

Thank you so much

Comment: A lot of people come here posting their homework assignments and basically expect us to do it for them. I think your question comes off that way a bit, which could be why you received two downvotes. Of course, it's impossible to know for sure because none of them left comments, but that's my hypothesis at least.

Comment: Oh okay I see. It's for an homework, but it's only a little part of it that I don't understand, and as I haven't see anything about something like that on Internet I tried here.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do what you're trying to do! One way is to use a "circular list". In a list each element also has a pointer to the next element. In a circular list, the last element points to the first element, so that you just keep wrapping around as you iterate through the list!

Writing our own circular list implementation is not too hard, but fortunately circular lists are accessible via the `srfi/1` library. One possible implementation using that library looks like this:

```
#lang racket

(require srfi/1) 

; function we will apply distributively to values in list
(define (1+ val) (+ val 1))

(define (distribute function l n)
  ; we define an inner function so we can take list l
  ; and convert it to a "circular" list

  (define (inner-distribute func circular-l n count)
    (if (> count 0)
        (cons (func (list-ref circular-l n))
              (inner-distribute func circular-l (+ n 1) (- count 1)))
        '()))
  (inner-distribute function (apply circular-list l) n n))

(distribute 1+ '(1 2 3 4 5 6) 4)
; this returns the list '(6 7 2 3)
; just like you specified in your question!
```

That `distribute` function does the job, but like I said, there are *many, many* ways to do this. I strongly encourage you to study the code above and understand it - with a small amount of effort you should be able to discover some solutions that are vastly superior to the one above. Good luck!

edit: In a comment OP felt like the above code was a bit too much for them to understand. Here is an alternative approach:

```
(require srfi/1) 

; function we will apply distributively to values in list
(define (1+ val) (+ val 1))

(define (distribute func l n)
    (map (lambda (x)
           (func (list-ref (apply circular-list l) x)))
         (range n (+ n n))))

(distribute 1+ '(1 2 3 4 5 6) 4) ; works!
```

The idea behind this solution is that we make a list of numbers from n to n*2, and then get the element in our circular-list indexed by each of those numbers and apply a function to it (in this case, 1+).

Comment: Thank you very much, but it's too high for what I have to do. I still keep it to one side to try to understand it properly as soon as I finish.
I managed to find something that works almost, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Sgt_Blaskowitz I edited my answer to include an additional solution that might help you understand how this problem can be solved. If you still need help you can ask me here or link me to your code and I'll walk you through it. Once you feel like I've cleared things up sufficiently you can accept my answer :)

Comment: This is my code now : https://pastebin.com/36CyP5sm

That's not finished at all, and I work on "plateau-ajouter1" to do what I asked.

And thank you for your second answer, i understand it more clearly.

Comment: @Sgt_Blaskowitz Some factors to consider while developing the function: 1. Check whether you will need to wrap around for a given case 2. What if you need to wrap around the function several times? For example, a small list given a case value of a high number. Good luck!